# In php class variable one equal second variable?

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
class Config {
static public $site = 'http://localhost/site/';
static public $style = $site . 'css/style.css';

// ...
}
```

This is not work for me. I get white screen.

```
class Config {
    static public $site = 'http://localhost/site/';
    static public $style = 'http://localhost/site/css/style.css';

    // ...
    }
```

This is work. I get design and code. Work very well. My question is Why?

Comment: Can you echo `$style` and share it with us?

Comment: [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) - `This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.`.... any concatenation of non-constant values, by its nature, is run-time evaluation

Comment: Nor would `$site . 'css/style.css';`` be valid anyway; it would need to be `self::$site . 'css/style.css';`

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible:

```
static public $style = $site . 'css/style.css';
```

Expressions cannot be used to initialize class values. Only constant values are permitted. This is something you'd have to do in the constructor, but since they're static values, there's no guarantee that the object will have been initialized BEFORE you try to access those statics.

```
class foo {
     public $foo = 1; // ok
     public $bar = 1+1; // ok only in PHP 5.6+
     public $baz = $this . $that; // not valid in any version of PHP
```

The only time you could use expressions (in php 5.6+) is if the resulting value can be calculated at compile time. so `1+1` is ok, because that can be handled at compile time. but `$this . $that` can only be determined at runtime, and is therefore illegal.

Comment: I see that. Thank you. Maybe that is better.